# RoutingErrors with static assets

Tags: heroku, assets

I'm having some issues with routing errors on my static assets. I keep getting the following error in my logs:

```
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/sprite-8bit.png" for 67.231.196.182 at 2013-03-20 00:11:12 +0000
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/sprite-8bit.png"):
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2013-03-20T00:11:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
```

I can't even find where there's a call to a sprite-8bit.png file in my code or assets

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with adding Hello Bar. I failed to add the image into the asset pipeline that it was trying to access.